# Having an issue with an exception (Stack overflow) being thrown when using an In Order traversal member function

Tags: c++, exception, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to test out my recursive In Order traversal function on a Binary Search Tree but I keep getting an exception thrown (Stack Overflow) when I call that particular function to display nodes on the tree. Am I missing a key part of code?

I've tried looking up how to handle the exception elsewhere but nothing has worked so far. I've also changed the function to a `const` because I wasn't sure if that's what the compiler (Visual Studio 2017) wanted. I have tested the Pre-Order and Post-Order traversal functions and both work as intended.

In-Order traversal function is a private member function of another class and is called by a separate public function that simply passes the `root` of the tree to `displayInOrder`.

```
void displayInOrder(TreeNode *&root) const {

        if (root == NULL) {

            return;

        }

        else if (root) {

            displayInOrder(root);
            cout << root->value << " ";
            displayInOrder(root->right);
        }
    }
```

> Exception thrown at 0x00C22FE9 in Binary Tree Application.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00CA0F60.

Comment: I always find it amusing when question on StackOverflow is about stack overflow.

Comment: Haha, that's exactly what I thought too!

Comment: `else if (root)` -- You already tested if `root` is NULL.  No need for the `else if (root)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
displayInOrder(root);
```

should be

```
displayInOrder(root->left);
```

The first version is infinitely recursive because you are calling the same function with the exact same parameters. This leads to stack overflow, as you've found.

Comment: Wow, that worked! I can't believe I missed that! You're a god send!

Comment: @ChristianDominguez If this is Visual Studio, when the exception is thrown look at the Stack Frame. That would tell you a lot.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the tip! @drescherjm